# Get values from SimpleXMLElement Object for php array

Tags: php, simplexml

I need help with this issue, it seems I can't get `targetCurrency` out of the `SimpleXMLElement Object`

```php
$xmlString = <<<XML
<channel>
    <title>XML ~~ Exchange Rates ~~</title>
    <language>en</language>
    <item>
        <baseCurrency>USD</baseCurrency>
        <targetCurrency>EUR</targetCurrency>
        <targetName>Euro</targetName>
        <exchangeRate>0.90900497</exchangeRate>
    </item>
</channel>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
        
foreach($xml->item as $rate){
    
    $rate       = (string) $rate->exchangeRate;
    $curr_code  = (string) $rate->targetCurrency;
     
    $money[] = array('rate' => $rate, 'curr_code' =>  $curr_code);
}
        
print_r($money);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rate] => 0.90947603
            [curr_code] => 
        )
)
```

`[curr_code]` should output 'EUR'.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same variable name for two different things:

```
foreach($xml->item as $rate){
    // at this point, $rate is the <item> element

    $rate       = (string) $rate->exchangeRate;
    // now $rate is a string with the exchange rate

    $curr_code  = (string) $rate->targetCurrency;
    // so now this won't work

    $money[] = array('rate' => $rate, 'curr_code' =>  $curr_code);
}
```

---

If you were running with display_errors switched on or checking your logs, you would have seen a message like this:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'targetCurrency' of non-object

Or in PHP 8, this:

> Warning: Attempt to read property "targetCurrency" on string

---

The fix is simply to name your variables more carefully:

```
foreach($xml->item as $itemElement){
    $rate = (string) $itemElement->exchangeRate;
    $curr_code  = (string) $itemElement->targetCurrency;
    $money[] = array('rate' => $rate, 'curr_code' =>  $curr_code);
}
```

Comment: Whoops, you are right, I overlooked that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try it using xpath instead:

```
$items  = $xml->xpath("//item");
foreach($items as $item){
    $rate = $item->xpath('.//exchangeRate')[0];
    $curr_code  = $item->xpath('.//targetCurrency')[0]; 
    $money[] = array('rate' => $rate, 'curr_code' =>  $curr_code);
 }
    
print_r($money);
```

The output should be as exptected.

Comment: So peel out one more layer. Works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @yello Glad it worked for yu!

Comment: The reason this works actually has nothing to do with XPath, which is massive overkill for this task; you fixed the actual bug without noticing, by changing `foreach($items as $rate)` to `foreach($items as $item)`